# Programmatically add views to a programmatically generated view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to programmatically fill a TableView such that there are 10 TableRows of 4 ImageViews. However, when I try to add ImageViews to the dynamically generated TableRows, nothing appears in the app.

I also need to store each ImageView in an array for later access, or at least store some kind of unique ID for each ImageView in said array.

My code is the following (within my MainActivity):

```
TableView table = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout1);
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i += 4)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);

    for (short j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        ImageView cell = new ImageView(this);
        cell.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(75, 75);
        grid[i + j] = cell
        row.AddView(cell);
    }
    table.AddView(row);
}
```

Comment: so whats the issue ? just set the id e.g "ij" i.e "00"  programatically which will become unique and will be easy to access

Comment: @AbdulKawee , none of the cells display in the app.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code, both stemming from the fact that cells in a `TableRow` have unique rules about their widths and heights. From the documentation:

> The children of a `TableRow` do not need to specify the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes in the XML file. `TableRow` always enforces those values to be respectively `ViewGroup+LayoutParams.MatchParent` and `ViewGroup+LayoutParams.WrapContent`.

Even though it's talking about XML layouts, this is true for layouts created in code as well.

So, first, you need something to define the height of your `ImageView` cells. Generally, you'd use `SetImageResource` or similar to make sure the `src` attribute of the image view was defined (note: **not** the background).

Second, delete this line:

```
cell.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(75, 75);
```

After those two changes, your code should work just fine.

Comment: When I directly appended the ImageViews to the TableView, they showed up fine (though, in one column, not in rows). I am using a subclass of the ImageView class which uses SetImageResource when it is created.

I tried deleting the line you mentioned and the cells still do not display.

Comment: Additionally, the TextView I append to the table directly after the rows no longer displays.